# How to return promise from a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am using knex, a library that returns a promise for PostgreSQL. I am hoping to use it like the pg library. My issue is that I do not see a way to return a promise from a method similar to how I can with pg as follows

```
var newObj = {

    getAllRows: function(callback) {
        return pg.query("select * from table",callback);
    },
};
```

which returns all of the rows with all data when calling `newObj.getAllRows`.

I have tried the same for knex, but it does not return...

```
var knexObj = {

    getAllRows: function(callback) {
        return knex('table').select("*")
               .then((data) {
                     return data;
             }
    },
```

Comment: If you are passing in a function for `callback` then you can do `callback(data);` instead of `return data;`

Comment: or better yet: `.then(callback)`

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working example. You return a `promise`. MDN explains it best in [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            }
            else {
                reject(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
};
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options here. Considder looking in the documentation of promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

I would advise to append your callback in the then queue of the returned promise like so:

```js
var knexObj = {

    getAllRows: function() {
        return Promise.resolve('MY DATA!')// stub for: knex('table').select("*") ....
    },
}

knexObj.getAllRows().then((data)=>{ // your callback!
  console.log("got the data:", data);
})
```

The benefit of this is, that you can chain the then statements together and don't have to pass callbacks forth and back.

Also you can catch all errors raised in one of the chain parts and try to resolve them by returning another promise.

```js
var knexObj = {

    getAllRows: function() {
        return Promise.reject('ERROR')// stub for: knex('table').select("*") ....
    },
}

knexObj.getAllRows()
  .catch(()=>{
    console.log("something went wrong but I can resolve this!");
    return Promise.resolve('Default Data!')
  })
  .then((data)=>{ // your callback!
    console.log('part result:', data);
    return Promise.resolve(data.split(' '))
  })
  .then((splitData)=>{
    for(let data of splitData){
      console.log('final data part:', data);
    }
  })
  .catch(()=>{
    console.log("something went wrong and there is nothing I can do about it!");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var knexObj = {
  getAllRows: function() {
    return knex('table').select("*");    
  }
}

knexObj.getAllRows().then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```